# Adding new elements to the top of the ListView

Tags: android, listview

I'm writing an IM client and I need to download (from filesystem or network) and show new elements at the top of ListView (it is history of messages -- older messages are at the top, newer -- at the bottom). I implemented my own Adapter for ListView but I can't add new elements at the beginning of the list and redraw it. (notifyDataSetChanged() isn't good for me, because indexes of messages in ListView changes and android can't redraw it normally).

How do other apps do something similar?

I don't create special code for it, I am simply creating new Adapter for my ListView:

```
messagesListView.setAdapter(new MessagesListAdapter(this));
```

And redefine getView() and getCount() method in MessagesListAdapter (extends ArrayAdapter now).

My XML for ListView is

```
<ListView
  android:id="@+id/dialog_messages_list"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/title_height">
</ListView>
```

And my XML for one element (one message) is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal" >

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/dialogMessageText"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text=""
      android:background="@drawable/dialog_message_in"
      />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/dialogMessageDatetime"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""/>

</LinearLayout>
```

May be you need other code?

EDIT: I tried

```
    messagesListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList));
    (new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            arrayList.add(0, "qwer");
        }
    }).start();
```

But it also not seems good. I tried to call `((ArrayAdapter<String>)messagesListView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();` in thread, but it makes exception.

Comment: Please post the relevant code and any errors you receive. There are **many** ways to do this. I would focus on how the history is sorted, not the ListView or Adapter.

Comment: Sorry, @Sam, I am long time versed in StackOverflow comments. Sorry. History is simply ArrayList<String> for example, but sometime I want to add new elements at the beginning of it. It may be Deque, if it's simple. Do I understand you question correctly?

Comment: Ok, where do you create the ArrayList<String> to populate the ListView?

Comment: It creates in another thread, and ListView accesses to it throwgh Static field of another class.

Comment: Would you post where you create and fill the ArrayList<String>?

Comment: Now for testing it is simply constant ArrayList with constant values "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8". I show it reversly (in getView() I get `List.get(List.size() - 1 - position)` instead of `List.get(position)`. When getView(6) will be called, I add new element to `ArrayList<String>` and call `notifyDataSetChanged();` New value appears, but old (which are show on display) are incorrect, because indexes (position argument) for them are wrong. Code for adding is `if (position == 6) { StaticClass.List.add("new"); notifyDataSetChanged(); }`.`getCount()` is `return StaticClass.List.size();`

Comment: I haven't any errors, all are working. But it isn't seems ok on the phone's or emulator screen. Old values replaces by new by parts. But I need simply add a new row at the beginning of the ListView.

Comment: Store your adapter in a variable and call: `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` Also "but it makes exception." What exception does it make?

Comment: @Sam, I of course attempted store adapater in variable. I get "android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.". Now I tried do it with help of AsyncTask and notifyDataSetChanged() in postExecute() and it seems work!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest reversing the order of the List to display the newest result first.

Run this example:

```
public class Example extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        String[] array = {"oldest", "older", "old", "new", "newer"};
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        Collections.addAll(list, array);
        Collections.reverse(list);

        // When you want to add new Strings, put them at the beginning of list
        list.add(0, "newest");

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

You don't have to override anything in the ArrayAdapter or ListView this way.

Answer (score 0):

you can programmatically add some views in the class associated with your list view. For example:

To add stuff to a layout and make new elements:

```
TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
EditText edit = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
relative.addView(tv);
relative.addView(edit);
```

This is to manipulate an existing element in the xml layout:

```
final TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.listItem);
    tv.setText("This an item I am changing");
```

If you look at some of the related questions, they will give your more information on this. But you can also checkout other people's custom listviews and adapters online. This one is really nice: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: But according the documentatoin (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) I can't add views to ListView. And I am really can't, I got the exception.

Comment: @jeremy-d, I got "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView"